# Directive contents are rendered before wrapping html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

im very new to AngularJS and now I wrote my first directive.
The directive represents a table row and the markuplooks like the following:

```
<table>
  <!--thead ...-->
  <tbody>
    <my-directive ng-repeat="(key, value) in object"></my-directive>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But the directive is renderd / printed out before the sorrounding table tags.
So my DOM looks like this:

```
<!-- multiple times -->
<my-directive></my-directive>

<table>...</table>
```

Heres my directive definition

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "/my-directive.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

    }
};
```

So why does this happen?

Comment: That is because you have invalid html there, browser just pushes it out. You may want to rethink on the element restriction and on the directive template so that it still renders as valid html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than `tr`, `td`, `tbody`, `th` elements never gonna work inside the `table` element. You should really use attribute directive so that it can support inside table to by doing `restrict: "A",` in directive.

```
<tbody my-directive ng-repeat="(key, value) in object">

</tbody>
```

If you want to have the other than table element to be there, then they could be placed inside `th` & `td`

Comment: Yeah this would make more sense.

Comment: @PSL Glad to have precious comment from guy like you.. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of going along with what Pankaj said, you can't call the directive from inside the table, its invalid HTML.
However, I can understand why you would want to use `restrict: 'E'`. Personally, I like using my directives as elements.

So, if you want to still use the directive as an HTML element The simplest fix to this would be to have your directive itself render the whole table. It could be a `<table-for/>` directive, or something like that.

This has been my workaround for this problem. Markup is markup at the end of the day, and you still have to play by the rules.

Answer (score 0):

So I came to the following approach:

```
<tbody>
  <tr my-directive ng-repeat="..."></tr>
</tbody>
```

And I restricted my directive to argument and it works. Thank you for your help.